# How admin can delete an entry from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, admin

```
<?php
            //connect to DB
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","3568");
$db_found = mysql_select_db("database");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");
$result1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `3568` ");
echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Delete</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
 {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Lname'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

   echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

I made this table on admin page which shows the data of the phpmyadmin table, and i would like to make a button next to each entry so admin can delete on his own the inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say nothing @Mureinik OP: *"Any ideas?"*

Comment: You know about the DELETE statement ?

Comment: You should remove your login credentials whenever posting on an online form.

Comment: Welcome to the stack. So based on connect string database name is 3568. You delete from a table so your delete stmt needs some work

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a delete "button".  Something like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
```

Assuming that `id` is the identifier (use whatever identifier you have), this would produce a link such as:

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=123">Delete</a></td>
```

Then you create a `delete.php` file, which gets the value being passed to it:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Validate the input to make sure it's usable in a SQL query.  Validate that the user is authorized to perform this delete operation.  Then use that value in [a DELETE query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

To create a delete button you have to use the  tag like this at the end of the instructions in the loop:
`<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">Delete</a>`

The data will be passed through the URL but be careful because anybody can change the values immediately from the URL.
Then you make a file which is going to contain the sql statement to delete the data from the database and don't forget the header function to redirect the administrators:

```
 header('Location:previous_page.php'); 
 $id=$_GET['id']
 $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$id");
```

The problem of this method is the security because data are passed through the URL. If an administrator want to change data, then he will just need to change the id from the URL and the data will be deleted without a possibility of coming back. You should think about asking a password to confirm the removal of data from database.

Answer (score -1):

```
Delete from myTableName where myColumnName=666
```

Or

```
Delete from myTableName 
where custLastname='SmithDuplicate'
```

Google something like "w3schools mysql" and tinker